# Backup Docker containers over ssh to tar.zst file

Tags: ssh, pipe, docker, cat

I've written a simple script to occasionaly export Docker containers to a remote NAS for backup.

I'm trying to learn how to use more traditional Unix tools in my scripts, so I wanted to do it using a single command - with pipes - that does the following:

- Exports the container
- Compresses it with ZSTD
- SSH's to the NAS
- Outputs the container file (tar.zst) to destination.

I've come up with the following (abstracted):

```
docker export $CONTAINER | pv |  zstd -18 | ssh $nasuser@$nasaddress  "cat > /remote/destination/directory/$CONTAINER.tar.zst"
```

However, this command fails - `cat` seems to read binary input and fails, complaining about '`no such file or directory`'.

I *did* get it to work if I export the container to a file first, and then run the command using the same file, but I'd like to know the correct way to do this (if there is one).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the complete, exact error message that you're getting when you run the command? Don't paraphrase it.

Comment: I bet the path on ssh host does not exist. It works for me locally.

Comment: Thanks for replying!

 The error changes, but generally looks like this:
 `-sh: line 1: `(▒/▒h0000755000000000000000000000000014022076531013223 5ustar  r00006600000000000000000604724612140135251750210450.▒͙▒▒P云▒cU▒▒oot(▒/▒h▒▒▒▒▒;2+,`H▒▒nk]d▒VI*▒%eJ[▒V$▒9i▒▒̗▒n▒eISK▒▒H▒0▒O&
              ▒x5▒In▒▒7▒G▒O▒▒▒Iڡ▒▒▒'
     line 35: cat > /path/to/destination/file.tar.zst: No such file or directory
`
The remote path does exist - it gets created automatically in the script if missing, and I can see it in the file browser.

Comment: You shouldn't have to export or backup containers. They're meant to be immutable. Rather, mount the files you want to backup onto the local filesystem and backup that part of the filesystem. Then you're just backing up files. Export is not for this. Containers should not be long lived. You don't need to backup most of a container, the layered image is enough and you should have that in a private repo that is backed up already.